# Bash: How do I smush all the args into a string?

Tags: git, bash, shell

Motivation: I am building a command `commitdeploy` which I want to accept very raw shell input:

```
bash$ ./commitdeploy this is my commit message
```

So I have a script that looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
...
git commit -a -m"$@" && ./deploy
```

Which produces:

```
fatal: Paths with -a does not make sense.
```

Here's what I know:

`$@` is the arg-list.

`"$@"` is the arg-list converted into a string that should show up as a single arg when used

My question is, what exactly is bash trying to send to `git`? If `git` is receiving `"$@"` as not a single arg then I think my characterization of `"$@"` above is incorrect. It looks like I need to stick more quotes in!

So, which one of the following, if any, are the right way, and why?

option 1: `git commit -a -m"\"$@\""`
option 2: `git commit -a -m\""$@"\"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `"$*"` instead of `"$@"` if you want everything in one argument.

This is a POSIX feature, so it will work in all POSIX-compatible shells and is not a bash-ism.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Don't use /bin/bash unless you really need bash-only features.
git commit -a -m "$*" && ./deploy
```

Comment: Boy is it hard to google for these things. There's gotta be a nice reference somewhere that tells me all i need to know about the difference between $* and $@. In fact, I know i've seen at least two webpages that detail this.

Comment: The difference between `"$@"` and `"$*"` is that the first one basically "passes through" the arguments, whereas the second one expands to a single string.  So `"$@"` is *special.*

Comment: Hmm. Okay. The way that the code is translated to instructions in a shell script is still a bit magical for me. But hey I know enough now to get this neat little script running. What's neat (and feels kind of dangerous) is I can actually do something crazy like put a glob in there and my commit message will gain the expanded glob

Comment: @StevenLu http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

Comment: Thanks @Amber, I found http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html#Special-Parameters to compliment that well (and gave me much-needed context)